# Understanding Tensorflow and keras and argument maxpooling

Tags: python, keras, model, layer

I use keras`enter code here` and tensorflow and gtsrb dataset or traffic sign detection. I have created the following model but the following error has occurred.My data is a photo and the training data is about ninety thousand.
My training data is as follows:
array of float64 (86989, 32, 32, 1)

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, input_shape=(x_train.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1), padding='VALID'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adadelta',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs =Nb_epoch,
              verbose=1, validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

The error is as follows:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 86989, 10, 10, 32]

Comment: error clearly saying, you built for this shape `(x_train.shape[0], img_cols, img_rows, 1)`, passed this `[None, 86989, 10, 10, 32]` , please replace first line `model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, input_shape=(86989, 10, 10, 32), padding='VALID')) ` it would work

Comment: it still has the following error:Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: [None, 86989, 2, 2, 32]

Comment: please understand network, now your input changed to `[None, 86989, 2, 2, 32]`, it was  `(86989, 10, 10, 32)`, input should be constant through out the network

Comment: Your input shape is incorrect, it should be input_shape=(img_cols, img_rows, 1)

Comment: As @Dr.Snoopy suggested, the input shape must not contain the batch dimension.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy lieben dank ,Thanks